# c++ map array operator overloading enable setting value to

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdmap

i try to do ordered map ( simple very simple ) 
i want to overload the map "[] = value "  operator . that is the equal sign that come after the array operator 
but how ?
i have this :

```
template <typename  K, class V>
class OrderedMap
{
    public:
        OrderedMap(){};
        ~OrderedMap(){};
        void setValue(K _k);
        void operator[] (K _k);
    private:
        std::vector<K> insertOrder;
        std::tr1::unordered_map<K, V> myTable;
};

template <typename  K, class V>
OrderedMap<K, V>::setValue(K _k)
{
    myTable[_k];
    insertOrder.push_back(_k);
}

template <typename  K, class V>
void OrderedMap<K, V>::operator[] (K _k) 
{
     ......
}
```

i have the array set and working but how to add the option to add value to key via array operator 
so this will be vaild

```
m_Map[CONST1] = "value"
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at [what `std::map` does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically operator[] is a function call which only supplies the parameters inside of the brackets to your class.

So in C++ you actually use the operator[] a bit different than let's say Delphi or C#:
The operator[] usually returns a reference to the item inside the collection:

```
myContainer[3] = value;
```

will actually resolve to the following:

```
MyItem refToObj& = myContainer[3];
refToObj = value;
```

the operator[] should then have the following form

```
MyItem& MyContainer::operator[](int);
```

If you cannot work with references for some reason (for example you don't actually HAVE a MyItem instance inside your container and the operator[] should convert the object into a different type) then the only approach is to use a "helper object":

```
MyContainer::Helper helper = myContainer[3];
helper = value;
```

the operator[] should then have the following form

```
MyContainer::Helper MyContainer::operator[](int);
```

where `MyHelper` is a special class which overloads the operator= which then does the container specific conversion (see `vector<bool>` if you're interested in this approach).

Edit:
To come back to the problem: I'm a bit unsure what you exactly want to accomplish, but I think you'd need to use the "Helper" approach:

```
class OrderedMap
{
    class ItemHelper
    {
    public:
        ItemHelper(OrderedMap& map, K key): m_map(map), m_key(key) {}

        //writing a value
        V& operator=(const V& v)
        {
            m_map.setValue(m_key);
            m_map.myTable[m_key] = v;
        }

        //reading a value
        operator const V&() { return m_map[k]; }
    private:
        K m_key;
        OrderedMap& m_map;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks , but is there no way to do it as std::map[] = ?

Comment: @user63898: added additionl information about this problem

Comment: The "helper" method seems overkill if `V` is default-constructible as you can just add a placeholder element to your map.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Depends on what exactly is the use case. If reading a value should have different behavior than writing a value it's the only approach I can think of. If reading should implicitly add a value, then I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator[]` needs to return a non-const reference to the indexed element:

```
V& OrderedMap<K, V>::operator[] (K _k)
```

In your function body, you need to check if that key is already represented in the map and, if so, return a reference to the corresponding value. If that key is not in the map, default construct a `V`, add it to the map, then return a reference to the value in the map.